# Lost all my google bookmarks even when synced

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I recently reset my computer due to a bug, and in doing so it deleted chrome. I made sure to sync all my passwords and bookmarks, but upon re-installing I realized they had all disappeared and reverted to some old bookmarks that I had (I already removed these years ago) I checked google forums but none of the solutions helped. Any advice?

Comment: @vicsar please read the question carefully before answering. *"I recently reset my computer due to a bug, and in doing so it deleted chrome"*